# Subtract output audio stream from input

Tags: c#, .net, audio, naudio

I'm using NAudio to capture audio from microphone, but it also cuptures sound from speakers. How can I filter it out?

Comment: Do you mean your NAudio capture includes the stereo out mix, or that your microphone is recording audio coming from the speakers?

Comment: Microphone recording sounds from speakers. I want to filter it

Answer (score 2):

This problems are called *Noise Cancellation* and/or *Feedback Supression*.

Both are (very) hard problems in digital signal processing and involve the *estimation* of a digital filter which approximates the transfer path.

Before you tackle such problems: it is probably better to:

- switch the speaker off
- use a better (directional) microphone